# 1" x 4" tongue and groove

Tags: wood

How much weight will 1" x 12" x 4' tongue and groove hold if it's supported on both ends? I am building a wheelchair ramp at a private residence and wonder if the tongue and groove will hold that weight. Should I use 2" x lumber instead?

Comment: 1" x 12" x 4'  ??  “That weight” ???     “Supported on both ends” ??   Please revise your question to include all pertinent details with a very thorough description of what you plan to do and how you plan to do it.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. a 1x4 supported at each end will not even hold its own weight without significantly sagging in the middle, much less any additional weight.

Answer (score 1):

Wheel chairs increase the psi due to smaller surface area. You need to have more supporting members and a thicker decking material. I would go with 5 total supports (two on outside and three evenly spaced in the middle; members should be 2” wide) and go with two layers of 3/4” plywood if used inside (outside would be pt 2” board). Those would support pretty much anyone. You also should think about transitions as well as maybe non-skid strips on the deck depending on the overall placement and usage.

You don’t say if it is inside or outside nor the length nor the pitch. These are important details as well as landing considerations.

This might help:
https://www.disabled-world.com/assistivedevices/ramps/ada-specs.php

Answer (score 0):

Before considering finishes like tongue & groove lumber you must first design and build a supporting structural frame underneath, preferably by someone with competence and with experience. If this is for a paying customer you may want to consider getting a professional designer or a structural person. Otherwise you may have a collapse and injuries.